# CMSMS formbuilder template

Tags: content-management-system

I hope somebody here is using CMSMS and will help me with a piece of advice.
I've been struggling for two days to find an answer. I'm quite new to this cms.
I need a two column form - half in left div and the other half in the right div.
The question is how do I arrange items (input + labels) with a specific class using smarty templates?
I've tried something like this:

```
{if $entry->css_class=='formgroup-right'}

<div class="right-side">
   ...............
</div>
{/if}
```

but it doesn't include all divs into one. I need to just modify the default formbuilder template. I need a pattern. I don't know if it's possible at all to do this using smarty.

```
    {if $entry->css_class=='formgroup-right'} // if entry css class is equal to formgroup-right then include all of them into div.right-side

    <div class="right-side">

{foreach from=$fields item=entry}
    {if $entry->display == 1}
        {strip}
        {if $entry->needs_div == 1}
            <div
            {if $entry->required == 1 || $entry->css_class != ''} class="
                {if $entry->required == 1}
                    required
                {/if}
                {if $entry->required == 1 && $entry->css_class != ''} {/if}
                {if $entry->css_class != ''}
                    {$entry->css_class}
                {/if}
                "
            {/if}
            >
        {/if}
            .................................................
     {/if}  
{/foreach}
     </div>
     {/if}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? Provide more details, so other users can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are a little vague here but if all you want is all inputs with class formgroup-right in a

```
    <div class="right-side"> ... </div>
```

and all with class formgroup-left in a

```
    <div class="left-side"> ... </div>
```

First arrange all fields for left together and all for right together

```
    100 field A  -left side
    102 field C -left side
    104 field E -left side give this class last-left
    101 field B -right side
    103 field D -right side
    104 field F -right side
```

Then in your form template

```
    {assign var=side value=0}
    <div class="left-side">
    {foreach from=$fields item=entry}
    {if $entry->display == 1}
         ...................
            {if $entry->css_class == 'last-left'}
                </div> <!-- end of left side -->
                <div class="right-side">
            {/if}
    {/if}
    {/foreach}
        </div> <!-- end of right side -->
```

This will go through the fields in the order you have arranged them and place the first fields in the left side div until it get to the last when it will close the div and open the right div.

That is if I understand your problem.